# Facing error during Merging manifest file in android studio

Tags: android

I added PAYTM SDK in my project and now I am facing a problem with merging manifest file since the library has its own manifest file.

So I am getting

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/logo) from AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-42
    is also present at [com.paytm.pgsdk:pgsdk:1.0.6] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-178:19 to override.
```

But after adding **tools:replace="android:icon"** in my application tag, my app has crashed at runtime by the following exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.demo">

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:icon="@mipmap/login_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    .
    .
    .
    </application>
```

Comment: Please change the app theme by changing android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: I already did it. See my last attribute of application tag

Comment: tried cleaning build after that ? after changing the name and putting replace tag ?

Comment: yes. But still not working.

Comment: Can you post your AppTheme? Most likely, your theme's parent is not of type Theme.AppCompat. Try changing that.

Comment: My theme's parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `icon="@mipmap/login_logo"` and `theme="@style/AppTheme"` from your Application Manifest and replace drawable ic_launcher in PayTM SDK with your app logo and that would do it.

Application will merge both manifests and you will get your desired theme and logo will be fetched from PayTM's manifest hence you would have replaced their ic_launcher with yours.

Comment: Make sure you are not making changes in the `debug/intermediate` manifest file. This is the ultimate solution please make sure you are doing things properly. Ultimately what you can do is provide a GitHub link to your code so that I can (or someone else) fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved that theme issue by removing conflicting AppTheme's style from SDK.